# Django - deleting a model instance - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: django

I have a simple `Delete` function to drop scheduled events. Here's the function:

```
def delete_sch_item(request, scPK):
    redirect_to = request.REQUEST.get('next', '')
    s = Schedule_Item.objects.get(pk=scPK)
    s.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
```

Every time I call this view by way of a url, it ALWAYS returns the error:

```
DoesNotExist at /schedule/delete-event/60/
Schedule_Item matching query does not exist.
```

Even though I look at the raw database and see that, yes, that item *does* exist. Even more confusing is that when I go back to viewing my list of scheduled items, the one that appearantly "Does Not Exist" has, in fact, been deleted.

What's going on?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason your view is being called twice. The first call deletes the object, and the second call throws the exception.

Comment: Whoa... I think it is late, because, of course, that makes sense. The problem what that the `redirect_to` default value of `''` meant that with no `next` parameter, the function was being called again. Thanks for the help! I was pulling my hair out.